# Are these usages 'when to, what to, how to + infinitive V' normal?

Tags: phrase-usage, questions

Are the usages 'when to + v, how to + v, and what to + v' are correct?

Are they shortened usages?

Are they normal usages?

There are some contexts for this usages:

The problem lies in deciding when to intervene.

How to download your google data?

What to expect for refunds this yea?

Comment: No. These aren't properly formed questions.  To turn them into questions, you need an auxiliary verb.  For example "How can I download . . . ?",  or "How do I download . . . ?", and "What can I expect . . . ?", etc.

Comment: What @BillyKerr said. *The problem lies in deciding when to intervene* is a straightforward sentence (an assertion). The other two aren't valid sentences (or questions) - they're just "noun phrases" (compare *I know **the answer*** and *I know **what to expect for refunds this year***). But it's worth noting that the words to look at are ***when, how, what*** - if the next word is ***to***, that's just an infinitive marker for the folowing verb.